# Sorting very large mysql table and writing to file

Tags: mysql

I have a very large table that I'm trying to sort and write to file with the query:

```
 select * from t1 order by user_id,tstamp into outfile 'sample.tsv';
```

The table is quite large (on the order of 600-700 million rows) and is using ~180GB on disk, and attempting to run the query gives me a "no space left on device" error, apparently writing so much data to tmp directory that it's maxing out the HDD and breaking the query.

I have maximized the free space on drive containing the tmp folder (close to 1TB free!) but the query is still failing with the same error, so I need a solution other than creating more space in the tmp directory.

The one idea I've thought of so far is to break up the sorting iteratively, leveraging the fact that for each of the 56000 or so user ids, there are an average of only 10-20 thousand records. Using some pseudocode, I imagine this would look something like this:

```
for each unique uid:
    select * from t1 where user_id=uid order by tstamp
    append result to file
```

I assume this would work (using the Python MySQL wrapper or similar) but is there a simpler, pure MySQL solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a better way, than your method of extracting by user id. You might want to use larger chunks. So long as the data fits in memory, the sort should be reasonable fast.

Although sorting all the data may not be feasible, you might be able to create an index on `user_id`. Such an index would speed your query. Without the index, each iteration would require a full table scan.

Building an index on `user_id, tstamp` probably would *not* help the query (even if it is possible). The problem is that the data does not fit in memory. Even if you had such an index, when you go to use it, you end up with a situation called "thrashing". The query would start to read the index. Each record would be on a separate page (to a close approximation). Soon, the page cache fills in memory. Then the engine looks at the next record in the index. It is almost certainly not in the page cache, so it has to read a page from disk. This situation continues. Each record-read requiring an additional hit to disk.

The solution to this problem would be a merge sort algorithm. In some cases, sorting outside the database is more feasible. But a 180 GB file is still pretty big.

Comment: Thanks - I've done some exploring of external sort methods (i.e. writing the unsorted data to file, then sorting in Python or similar), but they same more arduous than the method I've already proposed. There is already an index on user_id, so this should fast (enough).